# Mysqli select column names but skip first column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to display a list of column names from a table which works with the below code, but I would like it to skip the very first column (ID number). How can this be achieved?

```
$forms_colums = array();
$get_table_colums = mysqli_query($capital_db, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_customers ");
while ($found_table_colums = mysqli_fetch_array($get_table_colums)) {
    $forms_colums[] = $found_table_colums['Field'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add  `array_shift($forms_columns)` to the end, thus removing the first element from the array:

```
$forms_colums = array();    
$get_table_colums = mysqli_query($capital_db,"SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_customers ");
while($found_table_colums = mysqli_fetch_array($get_table_colums))
{
    $forms_colums[] = $found_table_colums['Field'];     
}
array_shift($forms_colums);
```

Comment: thank you so much, literally just made my day been researching for hours and within 5 minutes i had my answer thank you

Comment: @Nathan There are lots of ways to remove the first element of an array: `array_splice`, `unset`, `array_shift`. Where were you looking that you didn't stumble across any of these?